# I chmod directory 0777 but still get "file_put_contents failed, permission denied"

Tags: php, laravel

I spun up a new EC2 instance on AWS. This is a machine for a special project, it will run some new code for us.

Centos 7.9

PHP 8.1

Laravel 9.22.1

I then pointed my browser to a URL which looked like this:

http://ec2-44-316-175-207.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

I get a white page, apparently Laravel was trying to serve a 500 error.

I do:

```
tail /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

I see:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/storage/framework/views/f96fa4aeb95157abd9be7a2249115cf51f7628c6.php):

 Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:190\n

Stack trace:\n
#0 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(257): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError()\n

#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\{closure}()\n

#2 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(190): file_put_contents()\n

#3 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php(176): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->put()\n

#4 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(55): Illuminate\\View\\Compilers\\BladeCompiler->compile()\n

#5 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(139): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get()\n

#6 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(122): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()\n

#7 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(91): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()\n

#8 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(69): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()\n

#9 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(35): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->setContent()\n

#10 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php(57): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->__construct()\n

#11 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php(87): Illuminate\\Routing\\ResponseFactory->make()\n

#12 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(616): Illuminate\\Routing\\ResponseFactory->view()\n

#13 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(541): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->renderHttpException()\n

#14 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(447): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->prepareResponse()\n

#15 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(366): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->renderExceptionResponse()\n

#16 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(220): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->render()\n

#17 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(197): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->renderHttpResponse()\n

#18 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(233): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleException()\n

#19 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(257): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()\n

#20 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\{closure}()\n

#21 {main}\n
  thrown in /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 190
```

So I do:

```
chmod -R 0777 /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/
```

I try again but I get the same error.

So I open this file in emacs:

```
/var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:190
```

I edit this method to add some echo statements:

```
public function put($path, $contents, $lock = false)
{
echo $contents;
echo "<p> $path ";
return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_EX : 0);
}
```

Then I refresh the browser and I see:

```
startSection('title', __('Server Error')); ?> startSection('code', '500'); ?> startSection('message', __('Server Error')); ?> make('errors::minimal', \Illuminate\Support\Arr::except(get_defined_vars(), ['__data', '__path']))->render(); ?>

/var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/storage/framework/views/f96fa4aeb95157abd9be7a2249115cf51f7628c6.php startSection('title', __('Server Error')); ?> startSection('code', '500'); ?> startSection('message', __('Server Error')); ?> make('errors::minimal', \Illuminate\Support\Arr::except(get_defined_vars(), ['__data', '__path']))->render(); ?>

/var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/storage/framework/views/f96fa4aeb95157abd9be7a2249115cf51f7628c6.php
```

I'm having trouble reading this, though I worry this was already a 500 message before the fatal 500 message.

I read some other articles on StackOverflow, where a similar error is reported, mostly concerning the cache. I did run `php artisan cache:clear` but that had no effect.

I also did:

```
chown -R apache *

chgrp -R apache *
```

To ensure apache owns everything.

How do I continue to debug this?

Comment: Where did you get PHP 8.5?

Comment: You need to make sure that the storage directory is owned by the same user that runs the webserver. Existing files and directories won't be an issue, but any new directories and files could cause problems. The folder itself also needs to be able to be written to by the web user.

Comment: check who OWNS the files

Comment: apache owns the file

Comment: Typo: that should be PHP 8.1

Comment: apache owns everything in these directories

Comment: `ls -l /var/www/html/fs-mediation/mediation-api/storage/framework/views/f96fa4aeb95157abd9be7a2249115cf51f7628c6.php` what do you get?

Comment: Well, obviously I can't run "ls" on the file, since the file was never created -- that is the error above, that PHP was not able to create the file. But if I run "ls -l" on the directory "views" I see that the owner and group are both apache and permissions are 0777: "drwxrwsrwx."

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what the "s" is for.

Comment: It's not just about ownership. Proper selinux config is needed too. Don't just blindly wipe out security on your server if you don't know what you're doing. 777 is very dangerous.